# Error trying to use np.tile to insert repeated 1d array into column of another array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to fill an array column from top to bottom with a list that repeats.  A toy example is shown below, with the various approaches I have tried.

The "reshape" approach was the one I thought would work, but I get the "could not broadcast input array from shape (12,1) into shape (12,)" error.

```
>>> x = np.zeros((12,4))
>>> #x[:,0] = np.tile(range(4),(3,1))
>>> #x[:,0] = np.tile(np.array(range(4)),(3,1))
>>> x[:,0] = np.tile(np.reshape(range(4),(4,1)),(3,1))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [121], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 x = np.zeros((12,4))
      2 #x[:,0] = np.tile(range(4),(3,1))
      3 #x[:,0] = np.tile(range(4),(3,1))
----> 4 x[:,0] = np.tile(np.reshape(range(4),(4,1)),(3,1))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (12,1) into shape (12,)
```

Comment: Just `x[:, 0] = np.tile(np.arange(4), 3)`

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved without using `np.tile`:

```
x[:, 0] = np.array([*np.arange(4)] * 3)
```

Which will be faster than `np.tile` on such small arrays. numba usage will be the fastest for small and large arrays:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def numba_(x):
  rows_count = x.shape[0]
  range_ = np.arange(x.shape[1])
  for i in range(rows_count):
    x[i, 0] = range_[i % x.shape[1]]
  return x
```

Answer (score 0):

it came to me moments after I posted.  Just use a range of length 1 for the second index into x.  Tried, worked.

```
x[:,0:1] = np.tile(np.reshape(range(4),(4,1)),(3,1))
```

Comment: I recommend use [**Pig** solution in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17980931/mechanic-pig) if you want use `np.tile`, IMO, it is not very common to use `range` as you have used, particularly when you can handle the problem with numpy modules. Your solution will be slower than Pig one (around 2 times). Another point is that you don't need to write as `x[:, 0:1]` or `x[:, :1]`, it is more common to write it as `x[:, 0]` when you want just apply values in the first column.